# Should I use nominative or accusative after kun?

Tags: accusative

Which of the following is correct​?

- *Kun grandega potenco venas granda respondeco*
- *Kun grandega potenco venas grandan respondecon*

I guess that the nominative case must be used for *granda respondeco* since other sentences like *With him comes the cat* translate to *Kun li venas la kato.*

However, I'm not sure, since I got *Kun li venas la bluaj kato* for *With him comes the blue cat* but got *Kun li venas la bruna kato* for *with him comes the brown cat* on Google Translate.

Could someone please tell which is right and why? Google Translate is confusing me!

Answer (score 11):

Your sentence could be reordered like this and still have the same meaning (but with slightly different emphasis):

> Granda respondeco venas kun grandega potenco.

The *kun* is a separate phrase and doesn’t affect the case for the *granda respondeco*. The only thing that matters is whether the *respondeco* is the subject or the object of the verb (i.e., whether it is doing the thing or whether it is having something done to it). In this case the *respondeco* is doing the thing (coming) so it should be the subject. Another good indication is that *veni* is an intransitive verb, so it can’t have an object anyway.

So your first form is correct:

> Kun grandega potenco venas granda respondeco.

In general Google Translate probably isn’t a very good source to check your grammar because it tends to make a lot of mistakes with the accusative.

Comment: Dankon, @Neil Roberts , my doubt is clarified now! I'll stick with the original word order though, since I wanted to say "With great power comes great responsibility"! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

One of the rules of Esperanto Grammar is that a preposition is always followed by a nominative unless the accusative is being used to show movement towards the noun. (Salti sur la lito = Jump on the bed; Salti sur la liton = Jump on**to** the bed) *Kun* does not show movement towards an object, so it'll always receive the nominitive.

Comment: Although it might seem like it from the title, this question is not actually about whether the thing that directly follows _kun_ should be in the accusative, so I don’t think this answer helps very much.

Comment: The other noun (not being after a preposition and not the direct object of a transitive verb) would necessarily be in the nominative.